# Cannot launch react native debugger, react native packager is running

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-debugger

I am trying to console.log in a React Native project but the chrome tools will not load. The iOS emulator shows a warning saying remote debugger is in a background tab but there are no instances of a debugger open.. When I navigate to localhost:8081 it just says "React Native packager is running." with a link to the documentation homepage. I was just logging yesterday without any issues. Any ideas?

[image: Warning, Remote Debugger is in a background tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I figure this issue sometimes, just close your browser, disable Debugger, reopen your browser and open navigate to localhost:8081, enable Debugger now and re-load the app, this works for me most the times

Comment: That wasn't working for some reason but I don't think I actually closed down Safari, just chrome. I rebooted my computer and we are back up and running. Thanks for the quick response!